# jspm_packages does not exist on 'Stencil Init' of Stencil Installation

Tags: bigcommerce

I'm running into the following error at the 'stencil init' step.

```
The path you specified for your "jspm_packages" folder does not exist
```

The jspm_packages folder doesn't exist in my stencil directory. Is it supposed to be there? I'm wondering which part of the installation might have gone wrong in order for this folder to be missing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are seeing this, you can resolve it by installing jspm just in the directory you are working in. This doesn't help if you need jspm for other projects, but it will get you working for the time being with Stencil.

[Point 2 on this page](http://jspm.io/docs/getting-started.html)

Comment: It looks like my issue came at the github token step: https://stencil.bigcommerce.com/docs/installing-stencil-cli-1 I seem to recall this saying to add "default scope" which was unclear to me, but it seems to be specified in the docs now.

Comment: @rjfrizz @Alys This does not work... I tried to install jspm locally and then run `stencil init` but still have this problem. Can you explain the problem you had with the github token step; i dont understand what you are saying worked for you

Comment: @omar we no longer use jspm for the stock themes, we use webpack.

Comment: @Alyss That makes sense.... So I am new to stencil (like 1day)... I bought a stencil theme and now i want to edit it. The install goes well but when i get to `stencil init` I get the following error... Why does stencil think that i need it still `Please check your jspm.jspm_packages_path setting in your theme's config.json file to make sure it's correct.`

Comment: THANK YOU BTW... If nothing else i just need enough info to make a new ticket

Comment: Ah, well, for themes from PxU, they use JSPM and not webpack.